# How to rewrite a function without using async/await?

Tags: javascript

I've used Promise and async/await to code 2 functions that print provided word letter after letter with 500ms delay :

```js
function injectText(value, selector) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML = value
      resolve()
    }, 500)
  })
}

async function printWord(word, selector) {
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    await injectText(word.substring(0, i + 1), selector)
  }
}

printWord('Hello', '.hello')
```

```html
<div class="hello"></div>
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can rewrite `printWord` without using `async/await` to get the same
result. I understand that it kind of should produce something like this:

```
  injectText('H', '.hello')
  .then(() => {
    return injectText('He', '.hello')
  })
  .then(() => {
    return injectText('Hell', '.hello')
  })
  .then(() => {
    return injectText('Hello', '.hello')
  })
```

However, I have no idea how to rewrite `printWord` to achieve this. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use array reduce like so:

```js
function injectText(value, selector) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML = value
      resolve()
    }, 500)
  })
}

function printWord(word, selector) {
  return word.split('') // results in an array word.length long
  .reduce((p, _, i) => 
    p.then(() => // wait for the previous promise
      injectText(word.substring(0, i + 1), selector) // do the thing and return the new promise for the next iteration
    ), 
  Promise.resolve()) // initial promise for first iteration
}

printWord('Hello', '.hello')
```

```html
<div class="hello"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I need an hour to figure out what is happening :)

Comment: I'll try to comment it :p

Comment: Thanks, don't waste your time. I'll figure its out. That's good enough for me.

Comment: may be useful for others though :p

Answer (score 0):

```js
const interval = 100 
const word = 'Hello World !'
word.split('').forEach((letter, index) => setTimeout(() => console.log(letter), interval * index))
```

Comment: you've removed promises, not just async/await :p

Comment: Thanks, but you missed the point of my question. As you can see, Im using promises.